# Codeigniter3 - FormValidation - validate for boolean is always "false"

Tags: validation, boolean, codeigniter-3

I'm checking JSON input data with codeigniters native FormValidation library.
I've set up the validation rules like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
      'active', 'myCheckbox', 
      'required|is_bool'
);
```

here is the JSON data

```
    {
      "data": {
      "type": "items",
      "attributes": {
        "category": "5",
        "description" : "my description",
        "active": false
       }
      }
    }
```

**Problem:** The rule "required" interprets the input as not present as soon as the JSON value of `active` is `false`, so that the validation only succeed if value of `active` is `true`

**Question:** Is there a way around this, besides changing value of `active` into a `numeric` value `1`or `0` and therefore change lots of other correspondending code?

**EDIT:** trying `isset` instead of `required` behaves different, but also not satisfying

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules(
      'active', 'myCheckbox', 
      'isset|is_bool'
);
```

**EDIT No.2:** trying `in_list[false,true]` instead of `is_bool` behaves right, but the JSON does not look right anymore, because the boolean value must be sent as a string

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
      'active', 'myCheckbox', 
      'required|in_list[false,true]'
);
```

here is the JSON data

```
{
  "data": {
  "type": "items",
  "attributes": {
    "category": "5",
    "description" : "my description",
    "active": "false"
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is `is_bool` in `set_rules`? and where did you find this `is_bool` in user guid?

Comment: @M.Hemant
acording to the Codeigniter userguide: [link](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rule-reference)
 You can also use any native PHP functions that permit up to two parameters, where at least one is required (to pass the field data). `is_bool` is one of those

Comment: ok so are you trying to validate checkbox. and if the checkbox is not checked then you want to throw a validation error. am I right?

Comment: No. I want to check if the JSON field `active` is set -> therefore `required` and also make sure it's a boolean -> therefore `is_bool`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same probleam.
I fixed it creating my own "required" and my own "is_bool".
I created a "is_required_not_null" and "is_boolean" functions and put then in my helper, so I can use it where I need.
Note that I used [Identical](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) operator(===) to make sure of variables types and values.
See below...

Helper File:
/yourApplication/helpers/yourHelperFileName_helper.php

```
function is_boolean($value)
{
  try {
    if ($value === true ||  $value === false)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  } catch (\Throwable $th) {
    return false;
  }
}

function is_required_not_null($value)
{
  try {
    if ($value === null)
      return false;

    if ($value === true ||  $value === false)
      return true;

    if (is_array($value) && count($value) == 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      if (trim($value) == "")
        return false;
    }

    return true;
  } catch (\Throwable $th) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Usage sample:

```
    $data = $this->input->post(); //yours inputs ...

    $rules = [          
        [
            'field' => 'fieldName',
            'rules' => 'is_required_not_null|is_boolean',
            'label' => 'Field Name',
            'errors' => [
                'is_required_not_null' => 'Field %s is required.',
                'is_boolean' => 'Field %s must be boolean.',
            ],
        ],
    ]; //yours rules ...

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_data($data);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        //Valid Code ...
    }
    else{
        //Not Valid Code ...
    }
```

Source docs:

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#validating-an-array-other-than-post

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#setting-rules-using-an-array

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callable-use-anything-as-a-rule

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#setting-validation-rules